# Nothing showing up when I use router in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am struggling to see why nothing shows up when I use a router in my project (Just a blank screen). I simply installed react-router-dom as normal. I have tried changing the versions but haven't had any success

Here is the app.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import navbar from './components/navbar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<navbar/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
    
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is the navbar.js file:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
 
 function navbar() {
   return (
   <nav className='navbar'>
       <div className="navbar-container">
           <Link to='/' className='navbar-logo'>
                TRL<i className='fab fa-typo3'/>
           </Link>

       </div>



   </nav>
   );
 }
 
 export default navbar;
```

Comment: Which version of React Router. Should be 6 looking at your code

Comment: have you tried element={navbar}

Comment: try to make the `navbar` component capital as `Navbar` , you can also pass `element={Navbar}` directly

Comment: @ShoyebMemon I dont know why putting it in caps worked, but it did! Do you know why? Thanks :)

Comment: @OmarInuwa ill put an answer please accept it . it is because jsx needs to know if its a component when we specify it as a capital letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make the navbar component capital as `Navbar` , you can also pass `element={Navbar}` directly.

You need to Capitalize the name of your component for the JSX to understand it.
JSX won't know if that is an HTML tag or a valid JSX in this case a component.

**Nav js**

```
 import React, {useState} from 'react';
 import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

 function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav className='navbar'>
       <div className="navbar-container">
           <Link to='/' className='navbar-logo'>
             TRL<i className='fab fa-typo3'/>
           </Link>
       </div>
    </nav>
   );
  }

 export default Navbar;
```

**App js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/navbar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
     <Navbar />
       <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navbar/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router> 
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

In `JSX`, lower-case tag names are considered to be `HTML` tags.
That's why you need to capitalize the name of your `navbar` component otherwise `react.js` won't treat it like other valid JSX. It should be imported as `Navbar`.

So, your `App.js` will look something like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/navbar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navbar/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
    
    
  );
}

export default App;
```